# Characterization of a law by its moments in an interval

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A$ and $B$ be two random variables which are positive and bounded.

We assume that $\mathbb{E}(A^t)=\mathbb{E}(B^t)$ for every $t$ in an interval $[0,c[$ with $c>0$.

Can we deduce from this that $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution?

If $c=+\infty$, this is true because $A$ and $B$ are bounded, thus they have an exponential moment, thus they are characterized by their moments. However I do not see how to conclude if $c$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb E(A^t)$ and $\mathbb E(B^t)$ are analytic functions, so you can use the [Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)